# How to dynamically import an object exported from another file?

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

In my `node_modules`, I have a folder with an `index.js` which exports an object which contains a bunch of icon objects.

```
export { arrow1, arrow2, arrow3 .. }
```

I want to somehow dynamically import an icon object from another component. I am using Stencil.js, which is similar to React, and I need to use the icon string passed as a prop to dynamically import that particular icon object. How do I do that? The issue is that the import statement must be at the top of the page, but the prop is defined below.

Is there a way to import an exported object without using the import statement?
I tried with `fetch()` but it wasn't working. It kept returning `status not ok`.

Comment: Why are you rejecting `import` as a solution?

Comment: Because an `import` statement must be defined at the top of the page, and like I said, my props are defined below the `import` statement. I can't use `import` inside a function.

Comment: Why not import the icons you need and then select from them inside the function?

Comment: That is my question - HOW do I import only the icons that I need? It needs to be dynamic. The user passes the icon name string as a prop, and then I need to grab it, and import that particular icon. How? How to dynamically import? 
`import { my_icon_string} from ".."` How do I do that?

Comment: You could still import everything (if possible like `import all from "foo"` and then `all[name]`). otherwise you can use the function-like `import()` (and then do the same thing so you probably can get away with the first approach anyway)

Comment: I don't want to import everything. That would slow down the performance. I want to only import what is needed, nothing else. What function-like `import()` are you talking about? How do I use it? What is it? Please be more specific.

Comment: Well, either you import them all … or you try to do it at runtime in which case all the values are still exported from the same module so you'll still need to transfer the whole lot to the client.

Comment: Isn't there a way to somehow export the icon objects in a different way that would allow me to then import them (or fetch them) dynamically?

Comment: Why do you think that importing everything is any slower? Unless the problem is with webpack (or similar) but then you can use its directives to hep with bundling. Hard to say without seeing the model you want to import from

Comment: Maybe you should avoid using icons presented as JS exports in the first place.

Comment: @Quentin what would a better solution? We have a github repository with our own svg icons. The repository is installed as a dependency to our project, and we have created a component which serves as a way to import icons, like this `<my-icon-component icon={arrow-12} />`. What I want to do is get rid of the need to first import the icon, and then pass it to `<my-icon-component>`. Instead, I want the user to pass a string only, and the icon to be dynamically fetched somehow inside the component.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Because you are importing more objects? Otherwise you are importing only one.

Comment: Do you think it would be better to upload the icon objects to a database, and then fetch them with a server, or somehow make it work with github?

Comment: While a browser _might_ optimise an import like `import { some } from "foo"` vs `import all from "foo"; const { some } = foo` (stress on _might_ and even _if_ the difference is probably negligible unless you have 100k icons). You should check what your `import` becomes when _transpiled_ down for compatibility with older JS. Do not overcomplicate this. If you _really_ have a measured performance problem (or the bundle is really too big) then store those SVG as static files and import them with `import()` (and now the icon name is part of the path)

Comment: `You should check what your import becomes when transpiled down for compatibility with older JS..` - what is this mean?

Comment: While we're on the subject of performance, does anyone know how do I check the performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see point how importing all icons is a performance issue.
Here is small example, but it depends on what format are the imported icons.

```js
import { IconNames } from '../icon/types';

@Component({
  tag: 'custom-component'
})
export class CustomComponent {
   @Prop() iconName: keyof IconNames;
   
   render() {
    const unicodeIcon = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(getIconHexCharCode(this.iconName), 16));
    return (
      <span>{unicodeIcon}</span>
    )
   }
}
```

Comment: This consoles out `undefined`.

Comment: An icon looks like this: `const name = 'zoom-out-24';
const height = 24;
const width = 24;
const svgContent = '<path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M13.5 10.5h-6M22.5 22.5l-6.344-6.344M10.5 18.5a8 8 0 1 0 0-16 8 8 0 0 0 0 16Z"/>;';
var zoomOut24 = {
  name,
  height,
  width,
  svgContent,
};`

Comment: I suggest you create your Icon Font, that will make your life much easier if icons are used in more projects. You can use some online tool like https://icomoon.io/app. When you have your own icon font, there are more ways how to use it your web component.

Comment: What do you mean by `icon font`?

Comment: I have the icon svgs in a github repo.

Comment: Here is tutorial for it https://mediatemple.net/blog/design-creative/creating-implementing-icon-font-tutorial/, you have passed first step as you already have your icons in SVGs.